# Creating a empty collection throwing an error in Laravel

Tags: laravel, collections, laravel-blade

I'm returning a collection to a view and that collection is not always full. But in my view I'm accessing a value from that collection. And if the given collection is empty it crashes.

So my idea was to, if the collection was empty, populate it my self with keys and empty values like this.

Controller:

```
if ($collection->isEmpty()) {
    $collection->put('key1', "");
    $collection->put('key2', "");
    $collection->put('key3', "");
}else{
```

Blade:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="key1" value="{{$collection->key1}}">
```

But it just keeps giving me this error:

Property [key1] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel...

If I `dd($collection)` using `put` I get

```
Collection {#510 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    "key1" => ""
    "key2" => ""
    "key3" => ""
  ]
}
```

`dd()` with `$collection['key1'];` won't even get to the die and dump part.

Comment: Does it work with `$collection['key1']`?

Comment: @TimLewis Sadly not. Then I get: Undefined index: key1

Comment: I think you may try `value="{{$collection->get("key1")}}"` see: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-get

Comment: Sounds like your `isEmpty()` check is not working. I think you might need to post a bit more code; somewhere between your `$collection` definition and `$collection['key1']`, `key1` is not being set. If you run a `dd($collection)`, what does it output? (edit your question and add the output there please)

Comment: When you say " if the given collection is empty it crashes.", what exactly is the error that is thrown?

Comment: @Spholt Property [key1] does not exist on this collection instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access collection keys directly on the collection object.

Instead, you have to use the array access syntax like this:

`$collection['key1']`

or by using the `get` method like this:

`$collection->get('key1')`

The `get` method has the advantage of not throwing an error if the key is undefined.
Instead, it will return a default value. Normally, this would be `null`, but it can be overridden by using the second parameter of the function:

`$collection->get('key1', 'default')`

Assuming you are using PHP 7 or above, you can achieve a similar functionality with the [Null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) like this:

`$collection['key1'] ?? 'default'`

For further information, take a look at the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-get

Comment: A similar approach can be to use a null coalescing operator `??`. This will attempt the left hand expression and if it fails, return the right hand value as a default

Answer (score 1):

A Collection is basically a wrapper over an array, so you need to use array access to get to the underlying values:

```
$collection['key1']
```

Also, don't overuse collections. Yes, they can help out a lot with complex array manipulation, but they also come with an overhead. If you only use it to set or access keys, consider using a basic array or an object.

Comment: The comments already established that this isn't the whole issue. You're correct about object vs array access, but there's something else missing (`key1` is not being set in their code)